# List files that don't have any extension using command `dir`

Tags: matlab, file-extension, dir

In a directory containing files with different extensions, e.g. `.ext1`, `.ext2`, and   (no extension), how can I use the `dir`command to list only the files that don't have any extension?

The command `dir(fullfile('path/to/dir','*.ext1'))` will list all `.ext1` files, but I don't know of any option to read extension-less files.

Comment: I'd use a regexp to reject all files which have characters after a period, but of course this won't work if you use dots in your file names.  There is of course no way to distinguish "my.fancy.name" from "my.fancy.name.someextension" since extensions can have varying lengths.    If you know for certain that only `.ext*` extensions exist, then you can reject that specific pattern.

Comment: Oh that could be a good start! How can you reject an extension in `dir`?

Comment: Is there more information you can provide?  Does your directory have any dots in the filenames?  Also, do you know what kinds of extensions are available?  This is a bit difficult especially if there are files with dots in the names.  In addition, this doesn't escape the possibility that in your directory, there could also be nested directories, and they most likely don't have extensions too.

Comment: File names have dots in them, and extensions are either `.ncx`, `.gbx9`, or none. Nested directories won't be a problem in this case.

Comment: shame nesting directories is the simplest to fix... `folderContents = dir`  `fileNames = {folderContents(~[folderContents.isdir]).name}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try if the following fits all your needs:

```
allfiles = dir
filelist = {allfiles(3:end).name}

mask = cellfun(@isempty, regexp( filelist ,'[^\\]*(?=[.][a-zA-Z]+$)','match'))
output = filelist(mask)
```

The regular expression finds all filenames which **have an extension** and returns an empty array if not. Therefore `cellfun(@isempty, ... )` will give you the desired mask.

Comment: With a tiny bit of spin up this is exactly what I needed. Thank you.